# Eclipse - Types could not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, mbed

I installed Eclipse GNU ARM, I let it use the mbed cli tool chain:

Project > Properties > C/C++ Build -> Builder Settings:
Removed check Builder -> 'Use default build command'.
Build command: mbed
Behavior > Build (Incremental build): compile -v -f
Behavior > Clean: compile -v -c -f
All compiles and downloads fine!

However, I see a lot of errors that shouldn't be there. To name a few:

Type 'uint16_t' could not be resolved
Type 'AnalogIn' could not be resolved
Symbol 'PA_8'  could not resolved
Method 'read' could not be resolved
Function 'printf' could not be resolved
While AnalogIn could not be resolved, DigitalIn, DigitalOut and DigitalInOut actually can be resolved. Isn't that strange?

I searched the internet and tried to add project paths and paths to mbed-os:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprosessor Include Paths, Macros etc.
Project -> Index -> Rebuild
Project -> Index -> Freshen All Files
But no luck so far. Has anybody bee able to get that working better? Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards, Jack.

Answer (score 0):

If you export to eclipse using Mbed CLI it should set the paths already correct for your board (and include the right links to the standard library). Try running:

```
mbed export -i eclipse_gcc_arm -m YOUR_TARGET_NAME
```

And then loading the project in Eclipse.

Comment: Hi Jan, I use just "mbed export -i eclipse_gcc_arm". Could that be the problem? Can I just export again with -m flag?

Comment: You can just export again. You need to specify the target with -m to export.